# Processing 1 billion records locally in Spark from Hive metastore(parquet format) takes forever 6 hours. How to speed it up?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, parquet

I'm running everything in IntelliJ. The application is in Scala.

**scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
sparkVersion = "2.4.4"**

So I'm working with NYC taxi data. almost 1.1 billion records, 120gb data. I read it, drop the unnecessary data, clean it, and write to hive meta store in partitions(day, month, year) in parquet format with default compression. So far so good, it works rather quickly within a couple of minutes(2-3).
Now I read the data again from the metastore and do some operations, Basically, I want to compute all rides from manhattanToJFK so a few UDFs and a count eventually.
This takes forever.

Then I have a small dataset <1MB of weather data. almost 50 columns, I make a new DF out of it with only 7 columns. Have to find some correlation between the rides and the weather etc. So a join on the date and then spark.ml Correlation function to get the correlation matrix.
This also takes ages.

In total, all of it takes 6 hours to run(i was at 4-5 hours and I messed up something and had to restart). I can't wait this long to check if its accurate or not.

From what I read and understand parquet should work considerably faster than reading and working with CSV but I'm finding it opposite. So I think I'm doing something wrong. Maybe some config or setting etc?
I'm a beginner with spark and learning it by myself. So if I'm making a noob mistake kindly bear with me. Any help would be of great help.

If I should post any update or info let me know. I can edit it and post it.

Thanks

```
def analysis() = {
    var parquetDF = SparkObject.spark.read.parquet("spark-warehouse/location")
//      .cache()
    val manhattanTojfkDF = countManhattanToJKF(parquetDF)
    findCorrelation(manhattanTojfkDF)
  }

  def countManhattanToJKF(df:DataFrame):DataFrame = {
    var parquetDF = df
    //  val geojson = scala.io.Source.fromURL(this.getClass.getResource("/nyc-borough-boundaries-polygon.geojson")).mkString
    val geojson = scala.io.Source.fromURL(this.getClass.getResource("/NYC Taxi Zones.geojson")).mkString
    val features = geojson.parseJson.convertTo[FeatureCollection]
    val broadcastFeatures = SparkObject.spark.sparkContext.broadcast(features)
    val lonlatToZoneID = (longitude: Double, latitude: Double) => {
      val feature: Option[Feature] = broadcastFeatures.value.find(f => {
        f.geometry.contains(new Point(longitude, latitude))
      })
      feature.map(f => {
        f("location_id").convertTo[String]
      }).getOrElse("NA")
    }
    val latlonToZoneIDUDF = udf(lonlatToZoneID)

    parquetDF = parquetDF.withColumn("pickupZoneID", when(parquetDF("pickupZoneID") === "NA",
      latlonToZoneIDUDF(parquetDF("pickup_longitude"), parquetDF("pickup_latitude")))
      .otherwise(parquetDF("pickup_longitude")))

    parquetDF = parquetDF.withColumn("dropoffZoneID", when(parquetDF("dropoffZoneID") === "NA",
      latlonToZoneIDUDF(parquetDF("dropoff_longitude"), parquetDF("dropoff_latitude")))
      .otherwise(parquetDF("dropoff_longitude")))


    val boroughLookupID = (pickupID:String) => {
      val feature: Option[Feature] = broadcastFeatures.value.find(f => {
        f.properties("location_id").convertTo[String] == pickupID
      })
      feature.map(f => {
        f("borough").convertTo[String]
      }).getOrElse("NA")
    }

    val boroughUDF = udf(boroughLookupID)
    parquetDF = parquetDF.withColumn("pickupBorough", boroughUDF(parquetDF("pickupZoneID")))
    parquetDF = parquetDF.withColumn("dropoffBorough", boroughUDF(parquetDF("dropoffZoneID")))

    val manhattanToJFK = (borough:String, dropOffID:String) => {
      (borough == "Manhattan" && dropOffID == "132")
    }

    val manhattanToJFKUDF = udf(manhattanToJFK)
    parquetDF = parquetDF.withColumn("manhattanToJFK",
      manhattanToJFKUDF(parquetDF("pickupBorough"), parquetDF("dropoffZoneID")))

    val filteredDF =  parquetDF.filter(parquetDF("ManhattanToJFK") === true)
    val totalRidesFromManhattanTOJFK = filteredDF.count()
    println(totalRidesFromManhattanTOJFK)
    print(parquetDF.show())
    filteredDF
  }

  def findCorrelation(filteredDF:DataFrame) = {
    var weatherDF = SparkObject.spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", true)
      .load(URLs.weatherData:_*)

    weatherDF = weatherDF.select(weatherDF("DATE").cast("date"), weatherDF("AWND").cast("float"),
      weatherDF("SNOW").cast("float"), weatherDF("SNWD").cast("float"), weatherDF("TMIN").cast("float"),
      weatherDF("TMAX").cast("float"), weatherDF("PRCP").cast("float"))

     val joinedDF = weatherDF.join(filteredDF, weatherDF("DATE") === filteredDF("pickupDate"))
      .select(weatherDF("DATE"), weatherDF("AWND"), weatherDF("SNOW"), weatherDF("SNWD"), weatherDF("TMIN"),
        weatherDF("TMAX"), weatherDF("PRCP"))
    //    .cache()

    val ridesPerDay = joinedDF.groupBy("DATE").agg(count("DATE").alias("rides_per_day"))
    val cleanedDF =  ridesPerDay.join(joinedDF, "DATE").dropDuplicates().drop("DATE")
    cleanedDF.printSchema()

    val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(cleanedDF.columns)
      .setOutputCol("features")

    val corrFeatures = assembler.transform(cleanedDF)

    val Row(coeff1: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(corrFeatures, "features").head
    println(s"Pearson correlation matrix:\n $coeff1")

    val Row(coeff2: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(corrFeatures, "features", "spearman").head
    println(s"Spearman correlation matrix:\n $coeff2")
  }
```

SparkSession looks like

```
lazy val spark = {
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("NYCTaxiDataKlarna")
      .getOrCreate()
  }
```

and I pass **-Xms4g -Xmx4g** as VM options so it memory is 4.1 4.1 GB each.

**EDIT:** So I'm just running the manhatantojfk function now with a little change at the end basically persisting the data to hive so. next time I can start from there. and it's been running for almost 5 hours now and not finishing.

```
val dw = new DataWriter()
      dw.writeToHive(parquetDF, "parquet", "location_with_borough", "pickupDate")
      print(parquetDF.count())

      val filteredDF =  parquetDF.filter(parquetDF("ManhattanToJFK") === true)
      dw.writeToHive(parquetDF, "parquet", "manhattan_to_jfk", "pickupDate")
//      val totalRidesFromManhattanTOJFK = filteredDF.count()
//      println(totalRidesFromManhattanTOJFK)
//      print(parquetDF.show())
//      filteredDF
```

Comment: You need to share some code to suggest any improvements or to point out any mistakes.

Comment: lose your 2 udfs, and use inbuilt spark functions for their logic.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are not IO bound and so it doesn't matter what format you read.  What you really need to do is find the query plan (aka the actual work that spark is doing) and decipher that.  With out the query plan you cant tell if the problem is the initial read or the joins or groups or the correlate itself.  A good first place to look is the sql tab of the spark-history-server.  Additionally it usually better to dump the preprocessed data to storage before doing ML (aka cleanedDF) so you aren't rerunning the preprocessing constantly.

"I'm running everything in IntelliJ."

also how is spark configured?  Are you running with master = local[*]?

Edit:  So I'd suggest firing up the spark-shell and doing some REPL style code exploration.  If you have spark installed on your local computer start it from the command line with 'spark-shell'  When it starts you will see it print out the spark-history-server url.  From here run your code and then open the spark-history server to figure out what spark is spending its time on.

IMO your code looks more complex than it needs to be.  You may be unintentionally shooting your self in the foot and you won't know that until you dive a bit deeper.

```
➜  ~ spark-shell 
20/02/23 04:06:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.43.210:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1582459622890).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.2
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_231)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

//enter code
```

Comment: ok I understand. but i need the two udfs to find ZoneID from lon lat and then borough from ZoneIDs. So those two have to run on the full length of data. 
The join/correlate comes later. I can persist data with manhattantoJFK and then make a join and correlate. but its the same thing as before. 

Spark is just in IntelliJ. And yes,  master = local[*]
and I set -Xms4g -Xmx4g before it was less when i posted.

Comment: When spark starts up in intellij you will see a URL to the spark history server.  Go take a look at that.

Comment: also on your last dataframe do > df.exaplin(true)   This will also print out the query plan and what spark plans on doing.